# How to send and receive data between angularjs and asp.net mvc view

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I have an application completed in asp.net MVC. I am using Visual Studio 2015 in conjunction with Microsoft SQL Server 2014. Now I am developing an App in ionic angularJS that will run on a different server. Basically I want to run my app and pull the same complete list from my asp.net application and display it in my app.

I have CORS configured so that isn't a problem.
My issue is with sending anything from my asp.net localhost to the angularJS http.get function which is running on a different locahost`enter code here`.

I am creating an object in my controller and passing it to my view. Then in my view i'm running the object through JSON.Encode and passing that to a variable. I want to grab that variable from the view and pass it to my ionic angularJS app.

I am new to asp.net MVC so please be easy on me! Thank you!

http get function in my angularjs controller.

```
$http.get('http://localhost:50384/EventsInformation/TestJsonIndex')
.success(function(data){
        $scope.artists = data;
        console.log(data);
    });
```

object in my asp.net view. I just want to grab var data in my view and send it to angularJS http get function.

```
var TestMessage = ViewBag.Message;

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(TestMessage));    
</script>
```

Just in case you need to see my test object that I created in my asp.net controller.

```
public ActionResult TestJsonIndex()
        {
            EventsDetails TestEvents = new EventsDetails
            {
                EventsDetailsId = 1,
                artist = "Test String",
                ticketPrice = 34,
                ticketsAvailable = 232
            };
            ViewBag.Message = TestEvents;
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.get('http://localhost:50384/EventsInformation/TestJsonIndex')
.success(function(data){
    $scope.artists = data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

you console.log had no parameter passing through it and you could add your expression having that same controller using {{artists.anything}} since it is being attached to the scope artists. i hope this help though

Comment: I am parsing out my $scope.artists in my html file on the angular side. On the console log I forgot to put the data in there. the problem is when I see what comes through to with the data variable it is the actual html code in my asp.net view, not the json object in the var data

Answer (score 0):

And to send data through angular js to your asp.net api you will be needing this

```
$scope.addArtist = function(){
 var data = JSON.stringify({
  name: $scope.name,
  songs: $scope.songs
)}
var config = { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}}
$http.post("http://localhost:50384/EventsInformation/TestJsonIndex", 
data, config)
.success(function(data){
  $scope.showMsg = true;
  $scope.responseData = data.artists;
  console.log(data.records);
  })
```

}

Comment: I havn't tried sending anything yet from my angularJS file, but thank you. I will try that

Comment: I Tried this http post to send an object to my API and it doesn't work